# How to know how many commits between two specified commits?

Tags: git, commit

I know 2 specified commits (A and B) in my git. I want to know exactly how many commits are between them so that I can revert to the middle (C) of these two commits. Is it possible to do that?

BR

Comment: What do you consider to be the "middle" of a chain of commits like `a-b-c-d`, where `a` is a common ancestor, and `b,c` are parents of `d`?

Comment: Are you reinventing `git bisect`?

Answer (score 4):

```
git log --oneline A..B | wc -l
```

Please note that this includes `B` and excludes `A`. Add or remove 1 to the result according to what you want